# Transform TEME TLE derived positions of a GPS satellite to the WGS84 coordinate system for comparison

Tags: coordinate-system, gps, wgs84, satellite, ecef

I am trying to compare TLE derived x,y,z positions of a GPS satellite with those derived from precise GPS ephemerides (NGA). However, I am having some trouble getting the coordinate systems and reference frames to be compatible. The precise ephemerides are stated to be in ECEF--WGS84(G1762) and of course TLE positions are in the TEME frame. In the code below I have tried to do this conversion myself however as you can see in the plot, the offsets between TLE and precise ephemerides are massive (unexpectedly large -- 100's of km).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skyfield.api import load, EarthSatellite
import numpy as np
import datetime
import pytz
from skyfield.sgp4lib import EarthSatellite
from sgp4.api import Satrec, WGS84
from astropy.time import Time

from skyfield.sgp4lib import TEME_to_ITRF
import pyproj

desired_satellite = 1
eph_file_path = 'nga22741.eph'


def parse_eph_block(block_lines):
    position_data = []

    for line in block_lines:
        if line.startswith('P'):
            parts = line.split()[1:]  # Include all columns from the second onwards
            position_data.append([float(part) for part in parts])

    return position_data


with open(eph_file_path, 'r') as eph_file:
    parsing_block = False
    current_timestamp = ""

    for line in eph_file:
        if line.startswith('*') and parsing_block:
            # End of block, parse the data
            position_data = parse_eph_block(block_lines)

            # Process the data as needed
            for pos in position_data:
                satellite_id = int(pos[0])  # This assumes satellite ID is in the first column
                if satellite_id == desired_satellite:
                    position = pos[1:4]  # Extract position from the second to fourth columns
                    print(f"Timestamp: {current_timestamp}")
                    print(f"Satellite {desired_satellite} Position: {position}")

            parsing_block = False

        if line.startswith('*'):
            parsing_block = True
            block_lines = []
            current_timestamp = line.strip()  # Extract and store the timestamp

        if parsing_block and not line.startswith('*'):
            block_lines.append(line.strip())

# %%
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

eph_file_path = 'nga22741.eph'


def parse_eph_block(block_lines):
    position_data = []

    for line in block_lines:
        if line.startswith('P'):
            parts = line.split()[1:]  # Include all columns from the second onwards
            position_data.append([float(part) for part in parts])

    return position_data


timestamps = []
x_positions = []
y_positions = []
z_positions = []

with open(eph_file_path, 'r') as eph_file:
    parsing_block = False
    current_timestamp = ""

    for line in eph_file:
        if line.startswith('*') and parsing_block:
            # End of block, parse the data
            position_data = parse_eph_block(block_lines)

            # Process the data as needed
            for pos in position_data:
                satellite_id = int(pos[0])  # This assumes satellite ID is in the first column
                if satellite_id == desired_satellite:
                    timestamps.append(current_timestamp)
                    x_positions.append(pos[1])
                    y_positions.append(pos[2])
                    z_positions.append(pos[3])

            parsing_block = False

        if line.startswith('*'):
            parsing_block = True
            block_lines = []
            current_timestamp = line.strip()  # Extract and store the timestamp

        if parsing_block and not line.startswith('*'):
            block_lines.append(line.strip())

# Plot the x, y, and z positions over timestamps
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))

plt.plot(np.linspace(0, 1, len(x_positions)), x_positions, label='X Position')
plt.plot(np.linspace(0, 1, len(x_positions)), y_positions, label='Y Position')
plt.plot(np.linspace(0, 1, len(x_positions)), z_positions, label='Z Position')

plt.xlabel('Timestamp')
plt.ylabel('Position')
plt.title(f'Satellite {desired_satellite} Positions over Time')
plt.legend()

plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()

# %%


# TLE lines
line1 = '1 37753U 11036A   23220.32124156 -.00000093  00000-0  00000+0 0  9991'
line2 = '2 37753  56.7395  12.5133 0127297  56.1032 310.5169  2.00568283 88333'

# Load TLEs into Skyfield
ts = load.timescale()
satrec = Satrec.twoline2rv(line1, line2, WGS84)
sat = EarthSatellite.from_satrec(satrec, ts)

# Create a time range from August 7, 2023, midnight until 23:50 PM
start_time = datetime.datetime(2023, 8, 7, 0, 0, tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
end_time = datetime.datetime(2023, 8, 7, 23, 55, tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
time_step = datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
gps_timestamps = [start_time + i * time_step for i in range(int((end_time - start_time) / time_step))]

# Adjust timestamps by subtracting 18 seconds
adjusted_gps_timestamps = [ts - datetime.timedelta(seconds=18) for ts in gps_timestamps]

# Create a pyproj transformer for ITRF to WGS84 conversion
itrf_to_wgs84 = pyproj.Transformer.from_crs('EPSG:7789', 'EPSG:7664',
                                            always_xy=True)  # WGS84 (x/y/z) to WGS84 (lat/lon)

# Create another pyproj transformer for converting WGS84 (lat/lon) to Cartesian (x/y/z)
wgs84_to_cartesian = pyproj.Transformer.from_crs('EPSG:7664', 'EPSG:4978',
                                                 always_xy=True)  # WGS84 (lat/lon) to WGS84 (x/y/z)

# Initialize lists to store WGS84 Cartesian positions and timestamps
wgs84_cartesian_positions = []
timestamps_for_plot = []

# Loop through adjusted GPS timestamps
for gps_time in adjusted_gps_timestamps:
    # Calculate ECEF position using satellite.at()
    t = ts.utc(gps_time)

    eci_position = sat.at(t).position.km
    velocity = sat.at(t).velocity.km_per_s
    t_astropy = Time(gps_time)
    itrf_pos, itrf_vel = TEME_to_ITRF(t_astropy.tt.jd, eci_position, velocity * 24 * 60 * 60)

    # Convert ITRF coordinates to WGS84 (latitude, longitude, altitude)
    wgs84_lon, wgs84_lat, wgs84_alt = itrf_to_wgs84.transform(itrf_pos[0], itrf_pos[1], itrf_pos[2])

    # Convert WGS84 (latitude, longitude) to Cartesian (x, y, z)
    wgs84_x, wgs84_y, wgs84_z = wgs84_to_cartesian.transform(wgs84_lon, wgs84_lat, wgs84_alt)

    # Store WGS84 Cartesian (x, y, z) and timestamp for plotting
    wgs84_cartesian_positions.append((wgs84_x, wgs84_y, wgs84_z))
    timestamps_for_plot.append(gps_time)

# Convert positions and timestamps to numpy arrays for easier manipulation
wgs84_cartesian_positions = np.array(wgs84_cartesian_positions)
timestamps_for_plot = np.array(timestamps_for_plot)

# Convert lists to numpy arrays for element-wise subtraction
x_positions_wgs84 = np.array([position[0] for position in wgs84_cartesian_positions])
y_positions_wgs84 = np.array([position[1] for position in wgs84_cartesian_positions])
z_positions_wgs84 = np.array([position[2] for position in wgs84_cartesian_positions])

# Subtract the corresponding elements of the two arrays
delta_x = x_positions_wgs84 - x_positions
delta_y = y_positions_wgs84 - y_positions
delta_z = z_positions_wgs84 - z_positions

# Plot the differences
plt.plot(timestamps_for_plot, delta_x, label=r'$\delta_x$')
plt.plot(timestamps_for_plot, delta_y, label=r'$\delta_y$')
plt.plot(timestamps_for_plot, delta_z, label=r'$\delta_z$')



# Format x-axis as datetime
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

# Set overall title
plt.suptitle('GPS Satellite ECEF Positions')
plt.legend()

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

[image: TLE_VS_PE]